# How to disable the same person to play my RPG game as two different persons?

Tags: php, mysql

Of course, I store all players' ip addresses in mysql and I can check if there is a person with the same ip address before he registers, but then, he can register to my page at school or wherever he wants. So, any suggestions?

Comment: What about people who play behind routers - they'd all have the same IP when they hit your app, due to NAT.

Comment: May I ask why you would want that restriction?

Comment: I'm not sure that this prohibition is worthwhile... many genuine players might want to abandon one player for another or have 2 styles of player that they are trying to build up - if anything this shows the popularity of the game.  If you are worried about scripted players, as Jakub Hampl says paying is the most effective solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way that proves particularly effective is to make people pay for accessing your game.

Comment: I'm sure there are other possibilities that don't require your users to pay.

Comment: @Ponies: True, it's just any other way of blocking is so hopelessly easily evaded.

Answer (score 4):

Looking behind the question:

Why do you want to stop the same person registering and playing twice?

What advantage will they have if they do?

If there's no (or only a minimal) advantage then don't waste your time and effort trying to solve a non-problem. Also putting up barriers to something will make some people *more* determined to break or circumvent them. This could make your problem worse.

If there is an advantage then you need to think of other, more creative, solutions to *that* problem.

Comment: +1 This problem seems like a "think out of the box" sort of problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. There is no way to uniquely identify users over the internet. Don't use ip addresses because there could be many people using the same ip, or people using dynamic ip's.

Even if somehow you made them give you a piece of legal identification, you still wouldn't be absolutely sure that they were not registered on the site twice as two different accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the user's IP every time they log onto the game, then log users who come from the same IP and how much they interact. You may find that you get some users from the same IP (ie, roomates, spouses, who play together and are not actually the same person). You may just have to flag these users and monitor their interactions - for example, is there a chat service in the game? If they don't ever talk to each other, they're more than likely the same person, and review on an individual basis.

Comment: Could run into problems with people sitting right across from each other, when I would play video games with roommates or at a lan party we wouldn't use in-game chat to speak unless we had others who weren't with us on a team.

Comment: As I noted. Thus the human element to reviewing those users who interact when on the same IP. (... and plenty of people still use in game chat rather than actually talking)

Answer (score 0):

If its in a webrowser you could bring the information like OS or browser but this even makes it not save but still safer. 
It would take the hackers only a little more time and You have to look for the possibility that some people could play on systems with the same OS and browser

The safest thing would be that people on the same IP cannot do things with each other like trading or like in the game PKR (poker game) that you cannot sit on the same table.

An other thing would be wise to do is to use captcha's, its very user unfriendly but it keeps a lot bots out

Answer (score 0):

If it is a browser-based game, Flash cookies are a relatively resilient way to identify a computer. Or have them pay a minimal amount, and identify them by credit card number - that way, it still won't be hard to make multiple account (friends' & family members' cards), but it will be hard to make a lot of them. Depending on your target demographic, it might prohibit potential players from registering, though.

The best approach is probably not worrying much about it and setting the game balance in such a way that progress is proportional to time spent playing (and use a strong captcha to keep bots away). That way, using multiple accounts will offer no advantage.

Answer (score -1):

There are far too many ways to circumvent any restrictions to limit to a single player. FAR too many.

Unless the additional player is causing some sort of problem it is not worth the attempt. You will spend most of your time chasing 'ghosts' instead of concentrating on improving the game and making more money.

IP bans do not work nor flash cookies as a control mechanism either.

Browser fingerprinting does not work either. People can easily use a second browser.

Even UUID's will not work as those too can be spoofed.

And if you actually did manage to discover and implement a working method, the user could simply use a second computer or laptop and what then?

People can also sandbox a browser so as to use the same browser twice thus defeating browser identification.

And then there are virtual machines....

We have an extreme amount of control freaks out there wanting to control every aspect of computing. And the losers are the people who do the computing.

Every tracking issue I ever had I can circumvent easily. Be it UUID's, mac addresses, ip addresses, fingerprinting, etc. And it is very easy to do too.

Best suggestion is to simply watch for any TOU violations and address the problem accordingly.

Comment: Losers, control freaks, ... you must really hold computer scientists and others in high regard.